# Renpy guessing game riddle player interacting

Tags: renpy

I need to make the player to enter a scenario where he is asked to answer a riddle if it is correct go next lvl if does not go back to the beginning

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please provide more information about code that you have tried so far.

Comment: I've been trying with menu/ if / if == / with / $  trying to make a welcome page for the player then making him some question and given a multiple option to response and advance in game

Comment: Hello again guys I'm trying to make a game of riddles but for some reason it shows an error on the second option
This is the game of riddles

Comment: You can add your code by editing your question. Thanks for providing more information!